# How to hide the scrollbar while keeping functionality in a skewed div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I am trying to create a skewed div with scrolling content inside of it.

You can take a look at my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kDv45/1/

Originally I had it hidden by placing the content inside of a smaller div, but the skewing made the scrollbar visible again.

If I set the css overflow as hidden, it hides the scrollbar but it is no longer able to scroll. Can you guys think of a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use overflow : hidden on both x and y. And use JavaScript events for scrolling.